# CGIとして動作させた場合のUnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, python3, cgi

Webサーバーの、CGIで以下のコードを実行するとエンコーディングのエラーになります。

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

html_body = """
<!DOCTYOE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title> Test CAM</title>
</head>
<body>
こんにちは<br>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Button" onclick="button_click()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
"""
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print(html_body)
```

エラー内容は

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 153-157:
```

ただし、ファイルは

```
$ nkf -guess test.py
UTF-8
```

なので、utf-8のはずです

どうも、リダイレクトの折にエラーになるようで

```py
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

を入れて見ましたが、今度は

```
AttributeError: module 'sys' has no attribute 'setdefaultencoding'
```

とのエラーになります。

Python3ではどのように対処すれば良いでしょうか？

Comment: もしかしたら、これが参考になるかも。[CentOS 7.4 Apache Python 連携時につまづいたところ](https://www.monotalk.xyz/blog/centos-74-apache-python-%E9%80%A3%E6%90%BA%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A5%E3%81%84%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A8%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows10のpython3.6ですが、`python -m http.server --cgi`を[実行](https://qiita.com/goodboy_max/items/833d482827bf0efab45a)した場合は文字化けしました。

文字列がShift-JISで送られていましたので、[リンク先](https://imarismile.com/2018/08/09/post-7910/)のように[`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper)を冒頭に記述することで対処出来ました。

OSが違うので直接の回答になるかは分かりませんが、ご参考になれば。

変更前:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

変更後:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import io
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding='utf-8')
```